# How to clip this corners(on the screenshot) in UIPickerView?

Tags: swift, uikit

Yes! I tried use "clip to bounds" bun in doesnt work, and i dont now why. Notice to gray areas on the sides
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJtXp.png)

Comment: post your code also.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtPicker: UITextField!
    
    var testPickerView : UIPickerView!
    var testArr = ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five"]


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
        testPickerView = UIPickerView()
        testPickerView.dataSource = self
        testPickerView.delegate = self
        testPickerView.backgroundColor = .green
        testPickerView.layer.cornerRadius = 30.0
        testPickerView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
        testPickerView.clipsToBounds = true
        txtPicker.inputAccessoryView = testPickerView
    }

    // MARK: pickerView
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return testArr.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        txtPicker.resignFirstResponder()
        return testArr[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        txtPicker.text = testArr[row]
    }
}
```